# Error: Kernel appears to have died. Will start automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df which is actually a full merge of two other data frames. df has around 30115777 records. I want to get a subset of df where website matches with domain. I do the following -

```
df_subset=df[df.website == df.domain]
```

This throws me an error -

```
Kernel appears to have died, will start automatically.
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, how do you know? Shouldn't the call raise a MemoryError in this case?

Comment: Is there a way to increase the memory for that particular program?

Comment: @Dreamer, out of memory means it used all available memory on your machine. There's no special limit for the ipython kernel

Comment: You could try and put these values in a generator if you're running into memory problems